# window.open() alwaysLowered/z-lock not working

Tags: javascript, window.open

I get that 'pop-unders' are generally not great, but as this is a requirement of a current project, I'm attempting it. The main issue I've ran into is making sure the newly opened window is below the current one (the one that opened it). To open the window, I'm using the following:

```
function showPopUnder(e){
  var popUnder,
      strWindowFeatures = "scrollbars=no,alwaysLowered,z-lock,width=589,height=521",
      curWindow = window;

  function openRequestedPopUnder() {
    popUnder = window.open(some_url, some_name, strWindowFeatures);
    popUnder.addEventListener('load', function(){
      $(curWindow).focus();    
    }, true);
  }
  openRequestedPopUnder();
  return;
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I'm trying alwaysLowered, z-lock, and focusing on the current window once the new window is loaded. Tested in FF and Chrome. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried blurring the new window with `yourNewWindow.blur();` or making the current window have focus with `this.window.focus();`?

Comment: You cannot force browsers to do that stuff, at least not reliably. Some are more cooperative than others. You also can't be sure that your window won't open in a tab.

Comment: I didn't think browsers allowed pop-unders anymore.

Comment: @MattK didn't try with `this.window`, but I did try with `curWindow`...

Comment: @danwoods did you try to blur the new window?

Comment: @Pointy I'm fine with it opening in a tab, if that's how the user setup their browser. I just want the new window to be behind the current window when/if it opens...

Comment: @MattK, sorry, yes, I tried that...

Comment: Do those methods have any effect in any browser, or none at all (FF, Chrome, IE, Safari)?

Comment: Try using `$(popUnder.document).ready(function(){` instead of `popUnder.addEventListener('load', function(){`.

Comment: @MattK In FF and Chrome (the 2 I've tested with), everything seems to work properly except for the position/z-index of the new window...

Comment: @danwoods: Yeah, I don't think browsers let you use pop-unders anymore.  People have used them for evil moreso than good.

Comment: @RocketHazmat could be the case. Changing it to `document.ready` didn't change anything :/

Comment: @danwoods I don't think it's possible _anymore_. Ran a couple tests and nothing worked out. Used to be able to use `blur()` but that doesn't seem to want to work anymore as well as focusing of the current window.

Comment: @MattK thanks for testing, and for the info...

Comment: @danwoods See my answer below, might be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of clever trick since there doesn't seem to be any way to create a true pop-under, is to save the current window URL, redirect the current window to your 'popunder' URL, then open a new window to the URL you saved in step 1. It will seem as though it's a pop-under even though it's not. This depends of course if you can allow the user to refresh the current page or not.

```
<a href="http://www.popunder.com" onclick="fakePopUnder(this.href); return false;">Click Me!</a>

<script>
    function fakePopUnder(url) {
        var currentURL = document.URL;
        this.location = url;
        window.open(currentURL, '_blank');
    }
</script>
```